# How to fix / work-around NotImplemented error in sympy dsolve function?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I try to solve a system of 4 differential equations in sympy. I get a "NotImplementedError". Is there a workaround?

The set of ode's I am trying to solve is:

![ODE]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U4BR.jpg

I have tried substituting numerical values for the R12 to R45 symbols. I continue receiving the same error.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define symbols

m1, m2, m3, m4 = sp.symbols('m1 m2 m3 m4', real = True, positive=True)
c1, c2, c3, c4 = sp.symbols('c1 c2 c3 c4', real = True, positive=True)
R12, R25, R23, R34, R45 = sp.symbols('R12 R25 R23 R34 R45', real = True, positive=True) #0.2, 0.1, 2.7, 0.5, .6 
T1, T2, T3, T4 = sp.symbols('T1 T2 T3 T4', cls=sp.Function)
qp, qel = sp.symbols('qp qel')

T5 = 25 # ambient temperature

# Define equations
eq1 = -sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(T1(t), t)) + - (T1(t)-T2(t)) / (R12 * m1 * c1)
eq2 = -sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(T2(t), t)) + 1 / (m2 * c2) * ((T1(t) - T2(t))/R12 + (T5-T2(t))/R25 - (T2(t)-T3(t))/R23)
eq3 = -sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(T3(t), t)) + 1 / (m3 * c3) * ((T2(t) - T3(t))/R23 + (T4(t)-T3(t))/R34 - qp)
eq4 = -sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(T4(t), t)) + 1 / (m4 * c4) * (qp - (T4(t) - T3(t))/R34 + (T4(t)-T5)/R45)

eq = (eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4)
funct = (T1(t), T2(t), T3(t), T4(t))  

# Solve

sp.dsolve(eq, funct)
```

I expected to receive the symbolic solution for this set of differential equations. 
The result is "NotImplementedError"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for creating your equations is not correct. `Eq` needs to take two arguments, the left-hand side and the right-hand side.

```py
eq1 = sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(T1(t), t), + - (T1(t)-T2(t)) / (R12 * m1 * c1))
eq2 = sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(T2(t), t), + 1 / (m2 * c2) * ((T1(t) - T2(t))/R12 + (T5-T2(t))/R25 - (T2(t)-T3(t))/R23))
eq3 = sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(T3(t), t), + 1 / (m3 * c3) * ((T2(t) - T3(t))/R23 + (T4(t)-T3(t))/R34 - qp))
eq4 = sp.Eq(sp.Derivative(T4(t), t), + 1 / (m4 * c4) * (qp - (T4(t) - T3(t))/R34 + (T4(t)-T5)/R45))
```

I did this and dsolve takes a while to compute the solution. It has to exponentiate a 4x4 symbolic matrix, which involves finding the symbolic eigenvalues, i.e., solving a quartic, which is [very complicated in the general case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

SymPy could probably be improved here. Replacing symbolic parameters with numeric ones should make it go faster.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Could you enlighten me also on the syntax to pass the arguments (eq's and functions) to dsolve?

When I try 

`eq = [eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4]`
`funct = [T1(t), T2(t), T3(t), T4(t)]`  
`sp.dsolve(eq, funct)`
`
It results in the error  `'Tuple' object has no attribute 'expand'`.

I have tried to pass
`funct = [T1, T2, T3, T4] ` resulting in _object of type 'property' has no len()_.

I am getting more confused about the syntax of sympy. Does it work with lists, tuples, ...?

Comment: T1(t), and so on is correct. For the other error, you likely accidentally created a tuple somewhere. Check that `type(eq1)` and so on is `Equality` and that the types of `eq1.lhs` and `eq1.rhs` are `Derivative` and `Add` or `Mul`.